# Symfony2 existing route error

Tags: symfony

I'm having problems to figure out where exactly I have the error when getting this message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "core" as such route
>   does not exist.") in app/Resources/views/globalheader.html.twig at
>   line 3.

The globalheader.html.twig is:

```
{# app/Resources/views/globalheader.html.twig #}
<div id="globalheader">
    <h1><a href="{{ path('core') }}">MyListProject</a></h1>
    <div class="usermenu">
    {% block globalheader_usermenu %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

The routing.yml:

```
user:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /user

rpg_db:
    resource: "@RPGBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /rpg

core:
    resource: "@CoreBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

And the CoreBundle DefaultController:

```
namespace MyProject\System\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($name = null)
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or where else could be my problem?

Comment: The resource of the `core` is wrong: `"@CoreBundle/Controller/"`?

Comment: try with : resource: "@CoreBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `name` to your Route definition:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="core")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($name = null)
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```